# if-statement causes callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, callback

I have a jquery if-statement that causes an unwanted callback. Here's the code in question:

JQuery:

```
function test() {
    if ($('#' + '<%= tbNewRecipient.ClientID%>').val().length() < 1) {
        //TODO: add stuff
    }
    return false;
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddRecipient" runat="server" Text="+" ToolTip="Add Recipient" CssClass="narrow_button" UseUbmitBehaviour="false" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return test();"/>
<div id="divAddRecipient" style=" color:black; display:inline;" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbNewRecipient" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

This will cause an unwanted callback. When I just used this simple alert-window it worked without callback:

```
function test() {
    alert($('#' + '<%= tbNewRecipient.ClientID%>').val());
    return false;
}
```

Why am I getting a callback and how can I avoid it?

Comment: No parenthesis needed for length. just `.length`

Comment: @JqueryKing wow, that fixed it. Thanks! Do you know why the miss use of `.length` caused callback? I'm curious =)

Comment: Look at https://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: Being a @JqueryKing doesn't force you to show it in jQuery API. You can specify MDN too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `.length()`, just `.length`. That's causing you trouble.

```
$('#' + '<%= tbNewRecipient.ClientID%>').val().length
// -------------------------------------------------^
```

When you use `.length()`, which is not a property or method of the object, it throws an error making the `return false` not execute. So it causes the callback!

**Note:** The `.length` is a property, and not a method. Hope that answers!